# What is the Segula to own a set of Zohar?

Tags: zohar, segulah

In Derech Sicha (p. 152), Rav Chaim Kanievsky reportedly told someone who said he didn't have a Zohar for reference that it's a Segula to own the Zohar:

> אמרתי להרב שאין לי ספרי הזוהר ואמר לי שסגולה להחזיק בבית ספר זוה"ק זה
> כתוב כמדומה בחיד"א

What is the segula for owning a set of Zohar? (House protection? Torah learning? etc.)

Comment: R' Nachman of Breslev extolled his sefarim and said they are a segula for great protection over the house, also his wealth and also from all harms, even if just sitting on the shelf (Chayey Moharan #355).  Regarding wealth, also seems related to what he z"l mentioned, that whoever the Torah was transmitted through his hands, became wealthy, namely Moshe Rabbeinu (the chips of tablets), R' Yehuda haNasi through whom was the Mishnah, and R' Ashi etc. Gemara.  Related to Zohar bc R' Nachman spent more time in Tikunei Zohar than in any other sefer, and in a way Likutei Moharan is a perush on it.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this link [here](http://www.michael-center.com/?page_id=4584) where firstly it points to the [Pele Yoetz, Vol 1, letter zayin - 'zohar'](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14115&st=&pgnum=119&hilite=) where it writes expressly:

> ראוי לכל אדם ליקח לו ספר הזוהר הקדוש
>
> It is fitting for every person to buy for himself the Zohar HaKadosh.

When justifying why, the author of the article writes, (although I haven't yet found it in the said book):

> מדוע כדאי שיהיו בבית ספרי זוהר ?
> ספרי הזוהר מהווים צינור רוחני לשמירה, לברכה ומשיכת שפע לכל המשפחה. הרב יהודה אשלג "בעל פירוש הסולם לספר הזוהר"
>
> Why is it worthwhile to have in one's home the books of the Zohar? The books of the Zohar create a pipeline of spirituality for protection, for blessing, and a transmittance (lit. a pulling) of abundance to the whole family - [Rav Yehuda Ashlag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehuda_Ashlag) - The Ba'al HaSulam commentary on the Zohar.

So in answer to your question, based off this article, one could reason that the segulah provides protection, blessing and abundance to the family. But I will continued to bli neder research further :-)

Comment: It is worth noting this link - https://www.hidabroot.org/article/209418?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=pmd_9eb17a7d8c3ab04133df31fb712337eccc5381c2-1629042620-0-gqNtZGzNAiKjcnBszQi6 which lists a large number of segulos for learning the Zohar but I haven't yet seen outright if there is a standalone segulah for actually owning them

Comment: http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=9014&p=81576&hilit=%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%9D+%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A+%D7%A1%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94#p81576 - this forum brings your quote and the person writes that he has looked for the Chida that Rav Chaim mentions without success

Comment: Seems silly. The Pele Yoetz himself wrote the reason to own it. In order to learn it. And the author of the Sulam, possibly with negios, said to just buy a set to keep. Whatever.

Comment: @user6591 - it could well be but I am trying to frame it within the OP's question. Did you take a look at the link?

Comment: Yeah. My comment was assuming he was truthful about the statement from R' Ashlag. On second thought I wonder if a Kabala center has ne'emanus about this:)